# Gradle: How can I add a dependency existing on the server filepath

Tags: java, linux, gradle

I am working on a Windows Gradle project that works fine with Jars in the project Lib folder, but I need to add a Jar that resides in the filesystem of the Linux server to which the Java App will be deployed. I tried with ../../lib/xxx.jar, but Gradle doesnt find the Jar during build, obviously. I have to use this remote Jar and cannot simply copy and package it, also cannot use the url to the server. Need some reference to the server's file location. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The project needs the jar at build time or compile time?

Comment: called when the app is executed. the app itself is a jar on the server that gets executed from within another app. Only then the dependecy (jar)needs to be called. This dependency does some transformation on an incoming request.

Comment: If it is a dependency at execution time only then why do you need it at build time?

Comment: because in the code I am writing I need to import it as a dependency and it is referenced in the code I am writing where and when I use this dependecy to do transformations.

Comment: Think of it as a jar that you would normally put in the libs folder of your project (like bouncyCastle) and build it into the application Jar. Except now you world have to use that BouncyCastle that is already on the server.

Comment: Then it is a build time dependency that you have in a separate server. What access methods do you have from that server to access the file from the build machine?

Comment: The application jar is deployed in the same filesystem and has the same group and user and the dependency. The Development IDE is on a windows server with SSH and FTP access to the Linux server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255712/discussion-between-aled-and-home-of-creation).

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a Maven repository on the server that can be accessed by SFTP from the Windows build.

Example:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "sftp://repo.mycompany.com:22/maven2"
        credentials {
            username "user"
            password "password"
        }
    }
}
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:supported_transport_protocols) for more details on supported protocols.

Comment: Great. I'll have look at this. Thanks a lot!